# Openshift Platform - How to install expect package in the openshift platform?

Tags: installation, openshift, expect

I am trying to install the expect package in the openshift redhat cloud and Firstly i would like to know whether its supported and how to install the package.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the package installed (or considered for installation) is to open a Feature Request in Bugzilla (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=OpenShift%20Online) and also open a feature request at http://openshift.com/ideas.